# `npm install` Returns an errors

Tags: node.js, npm, angular, typescript-typings

I did step by step The guide of Angular : 
https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

And when I got to step of `npm install`

I get this error:

```
morwin@morwin-PC MINGW64 ~/Documents/angular2
$ npm install

> angular2@1.0.0 postinstall C:\Users\morwin\Documents\angular2
> typings install

typings ERR! message Unable to connect to "https://api.typings.org/entries/dt/node/tags/4.0.0%2B20160509154515"
typings ERR! caused by unable to verify the first certificate

typings ERR! cwd C:\Users\morwin\Documents\angular2
typings ERR! system Windows_NT 6.1.7601
typings ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\morwin\\Documents\\angular2\\node_modules\\typings\\dist\\bin.js" "install"
typings ERR! node -v v6.1.0
typings ERR! typings -v 0.8.1
typings ERR! code EUNAVAILABLE

typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
typings ERR!   <https://github.com/typings/typings/issues>

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.12
npm WARN angular2@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN angular2@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2@1.0.0 postinstall: `typings install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2@1.0.0 postinstall script 'typings install'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     typings install
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\morwin\Documents\angular2\npm-debug.log
```

So I tried to to continue with `npm start`

And i get :

```
morwin@morwin-PC MINGW64 ~/Documents/angular2
$ npm start

> angular2@1.0.0 start C:\Users\morwin\Documents\angular2
> tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite"

node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(39,88): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(99,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(174,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(24,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(26,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(105,123): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(105,165): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.d.ts(27,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.d.ts(28,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(1,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MapConstructor'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(2,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SetConstructor'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(7,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(8,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(11,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(12,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(14,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(15,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(100,41): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(101,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(102,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(4,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(5,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(70,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(2,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(8,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(9,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(10,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(10,93): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(11,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(11,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(12,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(12,149): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(13,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/component_resolver.d.ts(8,53): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/component_resolver.d.ts(12,44): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(62,148): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(103,144): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(108,139): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(109,135): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/reflection/reflector.d.ts(28,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/reflection/reflector.d.ts(30,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/reflection/reflector.d.ts(32,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/reflection/reflector.d.ts(34,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/reflection/reflector.d.ts(36,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/testability/testability.d.ts(40,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/platform_browser_dynamic.d.ts(75,90): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(10,66): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(66,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(66,70): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" `
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" '.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\morwin\Documents\angular2\npm-debug.log
```

What should I do to make it work ?

Comment: it looks like your npm is rejecting the certificate for the typings package.  all the other errors follow from typings being missing.  Try running this to disable strict certificate verification:  'npm config set strict-ssl false', then try 'npm install' again.

Comment: thank. but I get this errors : https://gist.github.com/morwin10/d430b0f3c7513b2b7aee47fce11a77bd

Comment: could you post your package.json?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/morwin10/17b51c73d65661c1566f17de4b57e62e

Comment: your package.json looks fine.

These lines are the problem:
typings ERR! message Unable to connect to "https://api.typings.org/entries/dt/node/tags/4.0.0%2B20160509154515"
typings ERR! caused by unable to verify the first certificate.

I haven't encountered that myself, so not sure yet what is causing it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112977/discussion-between-awiseman-and-moti-winkler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file name `.typingsrc` in your user directory

`C:\Users\morwin` - for example

That contain :

```
{
     "rejectUnauthorized": false,
     "registryURL": "http://api.typings.org/"
}
```

that's all

it works now !

Comment: This didn't work for me, but I did get things working with this package.json:

Comment: The configs here worked for me: [link](https://github.com/KevinRaffay/Angular2Sandbox)

Answer (score 8):

First Error "caused by unable to verify the first certificate."
It looks like a typings proxy issue. Create a file called .typingsrc and place it in your home directory.

.typingsrc:

```
{
    "proxy": "http://<proxyURI>:<port>",
    "rejectUnauthorized": false
}
```

Second Error "Cannot find name 'Promise'." (etc.)

In your tsconfig.json file, under "compilerOptions" make "target": "es6"

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "app",
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
}
```

Comment: What should I fill in <proxyURI> ?
I don't think I on proxy, because i checked my router ip (in 10.0.0.138 ..)  and  whatismyip.com, and it's same ip address

Comment: If you're not behind a proxy, remove that line.

Comment: I only had the second problem ("Cannot find name 'Promise'." (etc.)) and changing the target from "es5" to "es6" fixed it. I wonder why the AngularJs tutorial provides a target of "es5" then?

Comment: @jdebon: They are probably updating as we speak.

Comment: @Moti Winkler: The globalDependencies in typings.json are static. Before you execute 'typings install' try updating the dependency, execute 'npm run typings -- install dt~node --save --global'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you aren't copy correctly all files, is easiest clone the project of github, like this:

```
git clone ./my-angular-app https://github.com/angular/quickstart
```

Is a example most complete, and helpful.

Comment: You get the same error?, Do you have already installed globaly the TypeScrip compiler?

Comment: I made the guide of Angular. Which exactly compiler should I install?

Comment: First you need have installed the typescript compiler, you can install like this: `npm install -g typescript`, [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/#download-links),

Comment: I installed it. and `npm Intall` Returns :

https://gist.github.com/morwin10/2a5dade1867d09797ff559ceb4cb8c12

Comment: I think that i found the problem. The [documentation](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) says that you need a **node 5.x.x and npm 3.x.x version to work whit it**, other versions can produce errors... I have the 4.x.x lts installed and i don't have any problem is a bit strange.

Comment: For some reason, this repo: Https://github.com/mschwarzmueller/angular-2-introduction  work for me

I'm trying to understand why now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112979/discussion-between-koronos-and-moti-winkler).